# Instagram graph api testing phase

Tags: facebook-graph-api, testing, screencast, instagram-graph-api

i tried to have access to the instagram graph api but when i try to access the /media node of my account via the graph explorer tool i get 
"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (media) on node type (Page)",

Is it mandatory to send the screencast also to test the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't require to send screencast for Graph Explorer. You have probably missed setting up the Instagram business account. You can access the media node only via the instagram_business_account id that you get.

Here is the overview how you can set it up : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/

And incase you're facing error fetching the instagram_business_account id after following the documentation here is a way to resolve it :

[Instagram Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007928/instagram-graph-api/52216857#52216857)

Comment: Yes, it was the bug mentioned in the Instagram Graph Api question on so.

Comment: Quick question, how did you get signed up to use the Insta Graph API? Did you have to submit your app for review first?